# MySQL join on not equal with empty right table

Tags: mysql, join

I am trying to join two tables where the right table might be empty.
If it is empty I want all the records from the left table. 
If it is not empty, then I want all the records in the left table which is not present in the right table.
like so:
[venn diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4yf7.png)

Further more I need to filter the result so that tbl.free=1

I figured it would be a simple task like this:

```
SELECT tbl1.id, tbl1.name FROM tbl1 LEFT JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.id <> tbl2.fk1 WHERE tbl1.free=1
```

The result that I get with this is
When tbl2 is empty, I get all the tbl1 entries where free=1 - This is good
when there is an entry in tbl2 , I get all the entries in tbl1 - Exactly the same as above (not good)

What do I have to do to do this operation???

Comment: Please post your table structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a speculation, but you might need to add a condition to the `WHERE` clause which checks that a column from the second table is `NULL`, which indicates that a particular record in the first table did *not* match:

```
SELECT tbl1.id, tbl1.name
FROM tbl1
LEFT JOIN tbl2
    ON tbl1.id = tbl2.fk1
WHERE tbl1.free = 1 AND tbl2.fk1 IS NULL
```

Comment: That works like a charm, I had not tried it with the = sign.

Answer (score 0):

I had misread your request at first. All you actually want is all records from tbl1 that have no match in tbl2. No need to join. Simply a `NOT EXISTS` or `NOT IN` clause.

```
SELECT id, name 
FROM tbl1
WHERE id IS NOT IN (SELECT fk1 FROM tbl2);
```